# My passport cover is separated can I travel?

Tags: passports

My passport has gone for stamping , but due to mishandling of the fedex people the passport cover has come out . Can they still stamp visa on this passport and can I travel to Canada in this or do I have to re issue a new passport? My visa in usa is going to end soon .

Comment: You mean the passport book itself fell apart? Yeah, you're going to need a new passport.

Comment: Has the new visa vignette been already applied to one of the passport pages?

Comment: @littleadv that's a complete answer, i guess

Comment: New passport, and make a claim to FedEx for the old one. If you need to pay a premium for it to be expedited, it might be worth adding the cost of that on to your claim. (This is all assuming you insured the delivery, which I hope you would have).

Answer (score 4):

Modern passports have the biometric chips in the cover, so if the cover is separate from the interior, you can obviously *not* use it anymore - the cover could be from any other passport.
You need a new one.